# Accessing JSON Data NativeScript

Tags: javascript, json, fetch, nativescript

I'm a little new to NativeScript and JSON and I'm having a little trouble accessing the data in my JSON file. Right now I'm just trying to log some of the data out.

Here is the code in my view-model:

```
var config = require("../../shared/config");
var fetchModule = require("fetch");
var ObservableArray = require("data/observable-array").ObservableArray;

function StandingsListViewModel(items) {
var viewModel = new ObservableArray(items);

viewModel.load = function() {
    var url = config.apiURI + "getStandings.cfm?weekid=397";
    console.log(url);
    return fetch(url)
    .then(handleErrors)
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.json());
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(data) {
        console.log("hit");
        data.Result.forEach(function(standing) {
            console.log(standing.place);
            console.log(standing.username);
        });
    });
};

return viewModel;
}

function handleErrors(response) {
if (!response.ok) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
    throw Error(response.statusText);
}
return response;
}

module.exports = StandingsListViewModel;
```

And the JSON file that I'm referencing:

```
{
    "hiding": 0,
    "lastupdate": 1474481622,
    "refresh": 600,
    "showmax": 0,
    "showtie": 1,

    "displayColumns" : [
        "Points"
        ,"Wins"
        ,"TieDif"

    ],
    "users" : [

        {
            "memberid" : 910089, 
            "username" : "THE DAILY ROUTINE",
            "last_entry" : "1473446820", 
            "place" : "1",
            "record" : [
            "1.0"
            ,"1"
            ,"10.0"

            ]
        } , 
        {
            "memberid" : 2234158, 
            "username" : "MR. MANAGER",
            "last_entry" : "1473277680", 
            "place" : "2",
            "record" : [
            "1.0"
            ,"1"
            ,"26.0"

            ]
        } 
    ] 
}
```

I know this is probably something very basic, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Probably what is happening is you are getting the data, but you are not logging it so you can see it. You are doing:

```
console.log(response.json());
```

try doing

```
console.dump(response.json());
```

dump outputs json, log logs a string. So either stringify your json, or use console.dump.

If that doesnt work, try setting your headers.

```
return fetchModule.fetch(config.apiUrl + "getStandings.cfm?weekid=397", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }
})
.then(handleErrors)
.then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
})
.then(function(data) {
    console.dump(data)
    return data;
});
```

Comment: I found out that the error was coming from me calling .json() on a response that was already a JSON object (TypeError: Already read). Thanks a lot for the response though, I'll definitely use that console.dump() in the future.